# How to write the user type php code in HTML parameter?

Tags: php

First of all sorry for the title.

This is the code I have written but there is a problem, So decided to come here.

What I want actually that **Whatever I type in the value parameter it should be reflected back in the value parameter( for XSS )**. But I didn't succeed. Can anyone suggest me something?

```
<style>body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
<center><title>  </title>
<h1 style="color:blue;"><u></u></h1><br>

<center><form style="color:red"; action="xss3.php" method="POST"><center>


<b>Advance search:</b>  <input type="text" name="q" id="test" value="<?php echo ($_POST['test']);?>">   



<input type="submit" name="search" value="search"><br><br>
```

Comment: You are trying to perform an XSS inject on yourself or what are you doing? What value did you pass in?

Comment: use `if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){your logic}`

Comment: Any value. okay, let's take an example of a xss payload. Actually i want to understand behind the scenes to get the clear picture regarding xss. @chris85

Comment: @Ghanshyam Bhava hello, can you please clarify it by making adjustments to my code. Soi can have a clear picture.

Comment: The trick is to manipulate the browser. Try `"><marquee>I'm scrollllllling</marquee>`. The `">` should close your `input` then the `marquee` should be the standard element and will scroll (I think, have browsers stopped that yet?). Knowing what you typed would probably be far more educational for you.

Comment: Actually @chris85 i didn't get my reflected value and that's the main problem. There is something wrong with this code. So please check it.

Comment: What's a `reflected value`? What did you post, what did you expect?

Comment: Okay, I have a search box (which make the post request) in which I post anything like the string "**aaa**" anythinggggggg. But that "aaa" value didn't reflect back on the page.

Comment: You are using the wrong element, and not using error reporting. `name="q"` Although `aaa` has no relation to XSS so not sure what you really are asking about here. Seems like 2-3 different issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be you want:

```
<style>body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>
<center><title>  </title>
<h1 style="color:blue;"><u></u></h1><br>

<center>
// Redirect on same page with action="#". you can change
<form style="color:red"; action="#" method="POST">
<center>
<b>Advance search:</b>
<input type="text" name="q" id="test" value="
// Check btn submit
<?php if (isset($_REQUEST['search'])) {
    # use name of field instead of id
    echo $_POST['q'];
} ?>">   
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search"><br><br>
```

Make sure, you cant access posted value with the ID. you must need to use name instead of id. Here, i used same file for recieve requested data. you can copy the same file namely xss.php and put the logic there.

Hope this will help you! Greetings!

Comment: What is the use of this? isset($_REQUEST['search']))

Comment: This will determine wather variable($_REQUEST['search']) set or not and it is not null

Comment: hello, ghanshyam,  can you do me a favor? I want something in the code like when the null value submit. Should it be reflected back **No results found of your input?**

Comment: Its depend on your requirement how to gonna implement (basically dynamic/static). what kind of data you want to list out. If you wanna implement dynamic functionality go with this [example](http://www.webreference.com/programming/php/search/index.html) or with ajax [Ajax search](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope your php file name is also xss.php (which includes this code).

Assuming that, you need to do a few modifications.

PHP would accept the 'name' attribute in HTML input fields as the variable(associative array index) identifiers of $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST arrays.

There for you should change

```
<?php echo ($_POST['test']);?>
```

to

```
<?php echo ($_POST['q']);?>
```

There are a few methods to get rid of that error message:

**1st Method**

And to avoid the error (Undefined Index) at the initial page load, you may use the '@' symbol before the beginning of $_POST to suppresses error messages.

Then it would be: `<?php echo (@$_POST['q']);?>`

> If you use this method, at the end, your code may look like:

```
<html>

<style>body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>

<body>
<center><title>  </title>
<h1 style="color:blue;"><u></u></h1><br>

<center><form style="color:red"; action="xss.php" method="POST"><center>


<b>Advance search:</b>  <input type="text" name="q" id="test" value="<?php echo (@$_POST['q']);?>">   



<input type="submit" name="search" value="search"><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

**2nd Method**

Check if the submit button was pressed before displaying the result in the input box. We could use the isset() function to check whether the variable has been set. In this case `isset($_POST['submit'])` Here you can use two alternatives.

- Using the short hand if operator `<input type="text" name="q" id="test" value="<?php  echo isset($_POST['search'])?($_POST['q']):'';?>">`

> If you use this approach, your final code would look like this:

```
<html>

<style>body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>

<body>
<center><title>  </title>
<h1 style="color:blue;"><u></u></h1><br>

<center><form style="color:red"; action="value.php" method="POST"><center>


<b>Advance search:</b>  <input type="text" name="q" id="test" value="<?php  echo isset($_POST['search'])?($_POST['q']):'';?>">   



<input type="submit" name="search" value="search"><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

- Using if statements `<?php  if(isset($_POST['search'])){ echo ($_POST['q']); } ?>`

> And, if you use this approach, your final code would look like this

```
<html>

<style>body {
    background-color: #000000;
}
</style>

<body>
<center><title>  </title>
<h1 style="color:blue;"><u></u></h1><br>

<center><form style="color:red"; action="value.php" method="POST"><center>


<b>Advance search:</b>  <input type="text" name="q" id="test" value="<?php

 if(isset($_POST['search'])){
echo ($_POST['q']);

}?>">   



<input type="submit" name="search" value="search"><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want to check whether a null value was entered, then you could use this:

`<?php  echo isset($_POST['search'])?(($_POST['q'] == '')?'Your input was empty':$_POST['q']):'';?>`

Alternatively, you could also use if-else statements to check what is in the input, and based on that, you could display the result. 

I guess this is what you are looking for. If not, please be more specific about what you would like to do.